Call LWC from Aura , reset fields doesn't work
I'm calling LWC from Aura component , (im overriding the standard new button )
<lightning-record-edit-form>
<lightning-input-field ... 
...
<lightning-button label={LWC_Cancel} size="medium" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>

LWC JS
handleCancel(event) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cancelportefeuille'));
    }

i'm sending the cancel to the aura so in aura
Aura HTML :
<aura:component
    implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickAction"
    access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentRecordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="actvType" type="String" />
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" /> 

    <c:activityPortefeuilleStandardList   oncancelportefeuille="{!c.handleCancel}"  recordId="{!v.parentRecordId}">
    </c:activityPortefeuilleStandardList>

</aura:component>

Aura JS  :
({
    onPageReferenceChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(pageRef));
        var state = pageRef.state; // state holds any query params
        console.log('state = '+JSON.stringify(state));
        var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef;
        console.log('base64Context = '+base64Context);
        if (base64Context.startsWith("1\.")) {
            base64Context = base64Context.substring(2);
            console.log('base64Context = '+base64Context);
        }
        var addressableContext = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Context));
        let workspaceAPI = component.find( "workspace" );
        workspaceAPI.isConsoleNavigation().then(function(response) {
            if(response){
                component.set("v.parentRecordId", addressableContext.attributes.recordId);
                
            }else{
                var value = helper.getParameterByName(component , event, 'inContextOfRef');
                var context = JSON.parse(window.atob(value));
                component.set("v.parentRecordId", context.attributes.recordId);
            }
        })
        
    },

    
    handleCancel: function (component, event, helper) {

        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.isConsoleNavigation().then(function(response) {
           
            if(response){
                workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
                    var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
                    console.log('focusedTabId   :',focusedTabId);
                    workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
                })

            }else{
                var url = window.location.href;
                var value = url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                window.history.back();
                return false;
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
}

So when i'm in standard app i click on cancel i want to return to the previous page .
but when i click on cancel the form field values aren't reset , means when i open the form i Type XXX on the account Name i click cancel then i open the form again the account name isn't reset ..
Sometimes it works when i put in LWC JS handleCancel method
 handleCancel(event) {
        this.resetFields();
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cancelportefeuille'));
    }

resetFields() {
        getAccountRecord({ recordId: "$recordId" }).then(data => {
            this.WiredAccountRecord = data;
           // this.AccountRec.Name = this.WiredAccountRecord[0].Name;
            this.AccountRec.IsActive__c = true;
            this.accRecord = this.recordId;
            this.AccountRec.AccountManager__c = this.accRecord;
            this.AccountRec.AccountOwner__c = this.recordId;
            this.AccountRec.AccountCommission__c = this.recordId;
            this.AccountRec.ActivityType__c = LWC_Business_Portfolios_ActivityTypeField_NomPropre_Value;

        })
    }

whith this update sometimes the fields are reset sometimes not .. i'm confused ..

resetFields is asynchronous, so you're not actually waiting for the server call to complete. This can be a problem. Wait for the function to finish before you send the event.
async handleCancel(event) {
    await this.resetFields(); 
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cancelportefeuille'));
}

async resetFields() {
    const data = await getAccountRecord({ recordId: this.recordId });
    this.WiredAccountRecord = data;
   // this.AccountRec.Name = this.WiredAccountRecord[0].Name;
    this.AccountRec.IsActive__c = true;
    this.accRecord = this.recordId;
    this.AccountRec.AccountManager__c = this.accRecord;
    this.AccountRec.AccountOwner__c = this.recordId;
    this.AccountRec.AccountCommission__c = this.recordId;
    this.AccountRec.ActivityType__c = LWC_Business_Portfolios_ActivityTypeField_NomPropre_Value;
}

Where async essentially turns a function into a Promise, and await waits for a promise to resolve before continuing (effectively making the rest of the code inside the then of a Promise).

getAccountRecord({ recordId: this.recordId })

@Fark Yeah, I copy-pasted, should have read a bit closer. Thanks!

its Firas , your mate!
